# How to create a cmd with wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command, wxpython, command-prompt

I am trying to create a cmd in wxPython, one that performs similar to the cmd on windows, which has the same functions but also where i can add my own commands.
I tried this code but it give me all types of warning and erros:

```
import wx
import subprocess

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.prompt = "user@stackOvervlow:~ "
        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.default_txt = self.textctrl.GetDefaultStyle()
        self.textctrl.AppendText(self.prompt)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        self.__bind_events()


    def __bind_events(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.__enter)


    def __enter(self, e):
        self.value = (self.textctrl.GetValue())
        self.eval_last_line()
        e.Skip()


    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("Poor Man's Terminal")
        self.SetSize((800, 600))
        self.textctrl.SetFocus()

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.textctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

    def eval_last_line(self):
        nl = self.textctrl.GetNumberOfLines()
        ln =  self.textctrl.GetLineText(nl-1)
        ln = ln[len(self.prompt):]
        args = ln.split(" ")

        proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        retvalue = proc.communicate()[0]

        c = wx.Colour(239, 177, 177)
        tc = wx.TextAttr(c)
        self.textctrl.SetDefaultStyle(tc)
        self.textctrl.AppendText(retvalue)
        self.textctrl.SetDefaultStyle(self.default_txt)
        self.textctrl.AppendText(self.prompt)
        self.textctrl.SetInsertionPoint(GetLastPosition() - 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I need this in wxPython because i also want to create buttons next to the cmd. How can i create this? Thank you

Comment: What errors and warnings are you referring to?    Your code runs without error for me, except a couple of deprecation warnings.

Comment: @GreenAsJade If i run a command like "echo hello" it works fine but if i try to run it again i get this error(i know i am doing the command right: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\cmdtest.py", line 26, in __enter
    self.eval_last_line()
  File "C:\Python27\cmdtest.py", line 47, in eval_last_line
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect

Comment: Interesting.  I can't run a command at all using your code.   How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your

```
        self.textctrl.SetInsertionPoint(GetLastPosition() - 1)
```

to

```
        self.textctrl.SetInsertionPoint(self.textctrl.GetLastPosition() - 1)
```

---

Change your code to this,i corrected the issue.It was generating errors as the EVT_TEXT_ENTER event was appending the new line character to the text box,here i am using EVT_CHAR which resolves the error by making the input occur just after the `self.prompt`:

```
import wx
import subprocess

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
    kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    self.prompt = "user@stackOvervlow:~"
    self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    self.default_txt = self.textctrl.GetDefaultStyle()
    self.textctrl.AppendText(self.prompt)

    self.textctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.__bind_events)
    self.__set_properties()
    self.__do_layout()


  def __bind_events(self,e):
    if e.GetKeyCode() == 13:
        self.value = (self.textctrl.GetValue())
        self.eval_last_line()
        self.textctrl.WriteText(self.prompt)
    else:
              e.Skip()

  def __set_properties(self):
    self.SetTitle("Poor Man's Terminal")
    self.SetSize((800, 600))
    self.textctrl.SetFocus()

  def __do_layout(self):
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_1.Add(self.textctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()

  def eval_last_line(self):

    nl = self.textctrl.GetNumberOfLines()
    ln =  self.textctrl.GetLineText(nl-1)
    ln = ln[len(self.prompt):]
    args = ln.split(" ")

    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    retvalue = proc.communicate()[0]

    c = wx.Colour(239, 177, 177)
    tc = wx.TextAttr(c)
    self.textctrl.SetDefaultStyle(tc)
    self.textctrl.AppendText("\n"+retvalue)
    self.textctrl.SetDefaultStyle(self.default_txt)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
   wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
   frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
   app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
   frame_1.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you for this but for some reason still error and warnings. If i were to run command "echo hello" it works but i run it again get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\cmdtest.py", line 26, in __enter
    self.eval_last_line()
  File "C:\Python27\cmdtest.py", line 47, in eval_last_line
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect